# Connecting bluetooth headphones with Ubuntu 16.04 (Sony LEWH-H900N)

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones, sony

Trying to connect my headphones to Ubuntu but everytime that I try to pair, it fails. I downloaded Bluman and managed to get a connection, however, when I tried to switch the profile it would not let me, hence no sound.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you find the solution? I just bot the same headphones, I could not make it work yet